How can I go to the next slide of a PDF opened in Chrome, so that the next slide takes the entire vertical space of the screen?
I opened a PDF containing slides in Chrome. How can I go to the next slide, so that the next slide takes the entire vertical space of the screen?
Example of a slide that takes the entire vertical space of the screen:

Clicking on Page Down only shows part of the next slide, and still shows part of the first slide.

Firstly, please take note that this PDF viewer you have in Chrome is not the default Chrome PDF Viewer. It is the Google Scholar PDF Reader. So if you'd rather have the regular behavior you can uninstall the browser extension, and you should be able to use the Page Down for this.
But within this viewer, you can use the → (right arrow) keyboard key to go to the next slide.
